# UWP limitations in desktop apps

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

I know that the new UWP app model has some limitations when comparing to "traditional" Win32 apps.

Let's take Visual Studio Code as an example of a desktop app.

**What features of Visual Studio Code were missing or had to be different from user perspective, if it was an UWP app?**

EDIT:
I've done exams for microsoft certification "Essentials of Developing Windows Store Apps Using C#" and Exam 70-355: Universal Windows Platform – App Data, Services, and Coding Patterns. So I know something about win rt api.

Please don't bother with answers like "uwp app runs in sandbox". They are useless, because they say nothing about the limitations from users' perspective. I intentionally took real life example, so we can go concrete.

The limitation could be, that your app cannot support 3rd party plugins like custom syntax highlighter or refactorin extension(it was limitation of windows store apps, not sure if its still valid).

Another limitation could be, that your app is not able to take screenshot, because there is no api in uwp for it (not sure it its true, actually)

Comment: Way too long to explain here, and kind of off topic. I´d recommend you to just dive in the win rt framework and try for yourself. basically, all apps run in a sandbox "isolated" from the rest.

Comment: I dont need to explain the win rt. I'm not asking to. The question in bold is clear has definite answer, doesn't it. I know it's difficult to answer, but otherwise I would not be asking. The answer is difficult only because of lack of experience with uwp, which is case of everybody since it was released just recently

Comment: I think it is a very good question, begging for a specific answer from a knowledgeable person. However those are few and far between.

Answer (score 53):

The phrase "Win32 desktop app" is a ill-defined since the Win32 API programming model has been around since Windows NT 3.1. It can also cover dozens of development languages and UI frameworks over the intervening two decades.

Here's a quick overview of the key UWP differences:

- **API surface area.** The UWP platform supports many but not all Win32 and COM APIs, and introduces new APIs. If your "Win32 desktop app" is using mostly ANSI APIs that date back to Windows 95, then you have a lot of updating to do. If you are using mostly Windows Vista era UNICODE APIs, then a lot of stuff "just works". See [Win32 and COM API for Windows Runtime apps (System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps).
- **Security context.** The UWP platform runs applications in an AppContainer security context. "Win32 desktop apps" on Windows Vista or later run as "Standard User" or as "Administrator". UWP apps have less access rights than "Standard User" and can never run as "Administrator". UWP apps can request additional [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) to get a few more rights with permission from the user, but have limited access to the system and user data. For example, you cannot read most of the filesystem, only your installed location, an isolated application data folder, and an isolated temporary file folder. See [File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). This also means UWP apps have limited access to devices. See [Device and sensor overviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/).

> Windows Vista User Account Control that introduced Standard User was focused on protecting the system and other users data compared to the older "everything is administrator" model, but did little to protect the current user's data files since all apps could access or even modify it. AppContainer isolation is protecting both the system and the current user's data and settings. "Win32 desktop apps" were encouraged to install to `C:\Program Files` which was read-only at runtime and to use application data folders, but they were not required to.

- **Deployment via AppX.** "Win32 desktop apps" use any number of ways of deployment, often something using MSI technology and running as "Administrator". UWP apps are packaged in AppX files and are always deployed by the system. There is no "Custom Install Step", and therefore UWP apps cannot install drivers or services, change ACLs, etc. The system takes care of deploying the C/C++ Runtime (which must be Visual C++ 2015 or later).
- **Interface model**. There is a plethora of interface frameworks for "Win32 desktop apps" like WinForms, MFC, WPF, etc. The vast majority of these are not compatible with UWP because UWP does not support classic Win32 windowing, `WM_` messages, or GDI/GDI+. For UWP apps, you can use XAML with C++ or C# code-behind, DirectX (Direct2D and/or Direct3D) with C++ (or C# via 3rd party assemblies like SharpDX), or HTML5 with JavaScript.
- **Deployment via MSIX.**

Answering your question is therefore extremely difficult, if not impossible, without a complete understanding of the product's code base and dependencies.

See [Get started with Windows apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted)

Comment: I've quite good overview of what uwp is. I've read all the msdn atricles required to pass the exams for uwp. I was developing wpf apps since it existed. I just don't have real experience with uwp in development for desktop. I intentionally chossed VS Code as an example of a desktop app so it is clear what are the features, codebase and dependencies. The link you provided - getting started is exactly opposite of what I need to know

Comment: @user3384842 - was that UWP app *downloaded from the Windows Store*?  AFAIK, *WIndows Store apps* are never allowed to be run as administrator - that would violate the concept that such apps are always safe to run. On the other hand, if you installed the UWP from some other source, it may or may not have the option to run as administrator.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: There is a special capability that allows you to overcome all of the issues with UWP so that full trust Win32 process runs alongside your UWP app and you can communicate with that process. However you might have issues submiting such app into public Windows Store

Comment: The link *File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)* becomes [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions); *Device and sensor overviews* becomes [Devices, sensors, and power](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/).