# Configure UWP Native Messagging App

Tags: configuration, uwp, microsoft-edge, chrome-native-messaging, microsoft-edge-extension

I'd like to configure an [UWP App in order to receive messages from an Edge Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging), and to answer to these messages using some external configurations: I tried to use the [Windows Credentials Vault](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details), but it seems impossible to access it [(the UWP App seems running in a SandBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286806/uwp-limitations-in-desktop-apps), with no visibility of the Windows Credential Vault).
So my question is: is there a way to manually configure an UWP app without deploying the configuration into the store?

Thanks so much,

Daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best option, [but an UWP app can read a file from the local storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).
So, after the installation took place, I wrote a config file in the local storage directory (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\\LocalState), and I was able to access it from the UWP app using the following code:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile configFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("config");
String configContent = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(configFile);
//configContent now contains the config info
```