# Access to the File System UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, filesystems

I have to make a backup of a database through this code which must have access to the File System.

I added the references to the Package.appxmanifest as from this link and I also activated the app permission in the settings.

Settings -> Privacy -> File System and I have activated the app permission. This way you should have access to the files through the paths but it still crashes.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=user;pwd=password;database=dbtest;";
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ImportFromFile(file);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Package.appxmanifest:

```
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
  </Capabilities>
```

The error is:

> Access to the path C:\backup.sql' is denied.

Is there anything I overlook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UWP apps are limited and cannot be run as administrators. that said, you cannot do what you want in a UWP app.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286806/uwp-limitations-in-desktop-apps

Comment: Maybe this post could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724297/asp-net-getting-the-error-access-to-the-path-is-denied-while-trying-to-upload

Comment: But at this point it is possible to use MySqlBackup in UWP?

Comment: Hi @Grusi , Enabling `broadFileSystemAccess` can indeed access the file through the path, but it needs to be accessed through the method under the `System.IO` namespace. Some APIs used by `MySqlBackup` for file access are not supported and can only be used in Win32 applications.

Comment: Check Settings->Privace->File System->Choose which apps can access your filesystem and make sure your app is set to "On".

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this case is with the `MySqlBackup.ImportFromFile` method, which in fact uses `System.IO` APIs under the hood, which cannot access an arbitrary path  even when `broadFileSystemAccess` is enabled. To be able to access any filesystem path, you need to use the `Windows.Storage` APIs instead (`StorageFile` and `StorageFolder` APIs).

To make it work, you must use other methods `MySqlBackup` offers - either `ImportFromMemoryStream` or `ImportFromString`. For example:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=user;pwd=password;database=dbtest;";
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
var fileContent = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ImportFromString(fileContent);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```